# Shake a tree on chop

Tags: unity

I have a top down RTS type of game where the player (God mode style) can click a tree to chop it. I'd like to shake the tree where the base of the tree (where the position marker is) moves the least and the top the most to simulate like it's being hit by an axe so it shows visual feedback. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Not really sure where to start.

This would be in 3D.

Comment: You should specify if this is 2d or 3d (I'm guessing 2d)

Comment: My bad, it's actually 3D.

Comment: Perturb its position.

Comment: What's your experience with creating 3D assets for games and specifically animating them?  That kind of dictates the type of answer that would be appropriate for you.

Comment: Also, what is the art style - simple low resolution pixel style?  High res realism?  What kind of game can you suggest that might be similar?

Comment: I'm a programmer not an artist so skills on modeling is zero. Hoping for a programmable solution. It's cartoony style.

Comment: @Draco18s Any ideas on how to do that via code?

Comment: You said you're a programmer. I told you which property of the object to modify and the nature of the modification. That should be enough information.

Comment: There are many different ways to move a position but not all result in a good shaking look and feel. Thought maybe this was a common thing and some code out there already. That's like when someone asks how to do networking and you tell them to send the pos/rot to the server and back to the clients...

Comment: But I gave you an answer which is imo a reasonable solution and you haven't replied to it. Perhaps you're expecting full on copy paste code. If you are a programmer like you said you have to get your hands dirty, mate.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a library yes. There are thousands of libraries for unity on their asset store and others that have code that isn't on the asset store. Part me being a programmer is first not duplicating code :). On further thinking I believe it's rotation value that needs to be changed not position as when shaking a tree the base would stay still (where the anchor is) and it just kind of rocks back and forth. Getting that shake just right is the question. I'll check out camera shake scripts on the asset store and go from there. Thanks.

Comment: By duplicating code you mean reinventing the wheel, no you shouldn't. But you have to integrate certain things yourself. If you just wanted an asset library then A: you didn't specify that in your question. B: this is not the place to ask any of that. Also with my solution you're not changing the position of the object, you're moving certain vertices based on their vertex color. The trunk stays in place. If you just want to shake the tree simply add some noise to the position or use a tweener to do it for you. You haven't given a reason why you aren't satisfied with the answer given.

Comment: Sorry, I mistook "Perturb its position." from the comments as something you said.  You're answer is good, I just don't use those tools as I'm a coder so I don't get into blender or any modeling tool. I'll accept it because I didn't specify in my question just the comments. Thanks.

Comment: Vertex painting in Blender is easy tho. Granted you have to learn the interface. I'm a coder too, personally I think it's handy to know some basics regarding graphical tools. You don't have to go knee deep, something like vertex painting is trivial.

Comment: It looks like Unity has it's own animation tool that seems fairly simple. Perhaps I could use that to make a basic shacking animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Shaderlab, however concept doesn't change.

- Use vertex painting to color the parts you want to move. You can do this in your modeling tool. [In Blender](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/painting/vertex_paint/introduction.html).
- In your vertex shader use the color channels ( RGB ) of each vertex as how much to displace over time. Channel values should range from 0 to 1. You can just use the red channel (green and blue are cool too) or all channels to do some funky stuff. For example black ( value 0 ) means absolutely rigid. You probably want to apply that to your base. This part doesn't move. And the higher you go the more red it gets ( value 0  to 1.0 ) the shakier it is. Really depends on how you use these values to displace/animate your vertices.

[Manual for vertex data in shader](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-VertexProgramInputs.html) Scroll down for the color example

Alternatively you could use animations with bones or have the leafs separate and shake that in script. Not sure how performance heavy that is when you have plenty of trees. I don't know how your trees are setup and I'm not entirely sure how my solution scales to instancing either. If someone else can comment on that, that would be great.

Comment: Natalie Burke gave a good GDC talk on how these types of vertex-colour-weighted animations were used in Destiny. The video is members-only but the [slides may help spark some ideas](http://gdcvault.com/play/1022965/Animating-With). :)

Comment: Thanks for the slides. Shame the talk isn't available to all.

Comment: A form of this technique was also used for [foliage animation in Uncharted 4](http://www.gameanim.com/2016/08/13/shader-animation-uncharted-4/). :)

Comment: I know about these techniques but never realize to what extend they are used. These things are pretty neat.